# Finding a generator of a subgroup for ElGamal algorithm in java?

Tags: java, random, cryptography, rsa, generator

I am trying to find a generator which is smaller than 1024 bits.

p is a random 1024 bit prime number.

q is a random 160 bit prime that divides p-1.

---

I have already found the values of p and q. But the generator always ends up being 0 or 1.

Help is much appreciated.

```
BigInteger alpha=new BigInteger(1022,rand);//finding a biginteger smaller than 1024 bits

    BigInteger modInverseQ= q.modInverse(p); // (q^-1) mod(p)   
    BigInteger y = p.subtract(one);  //p-1
    BigInteger z = y.multiply(modInverseQ);  //(p-1)*(q^-1)
    BigInteger g = alpha.modPow(z, p);  // a^(p-1)*(q^-1) mod(p)

    int comp = g.compareTo(one);  // checking if generator is equal to 1

    while(comp == 0)    //if generator is 1 find a new generator
    {   
        alpha=new BigInteger(1022,rand);
        g = alpha.modPow(z, p); 
        comp = g.compareTo(one);

    }
```

Comment: I would just write `while (g.compareTo(one) == 0)` personally.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the implementation of the following class:  `org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.DSAParametersGenerator` .

It is a class of Bouncy Castle (https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html), a Java cryptographic provider.

Within it, there are several private methods that could be very useful for what you need.